# touchesMoved behavior in iPhone and Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, touch, touchesmoved

The function `touchesMoved` behaves differently in iPhone and simulator.

The repeating interval (refresh rate) of the function `touchesMoved` is much faster than simulator. Is there a way to deal with the difference?

Comment: When you say "much faster than simulator," did you mean "much faster on simulator?" Many things are much faster on simulator, but this shouldn't matter to your program; if you're relying on a particular refresh rate, then you're not going to work anyway (because it's not guaranteed). What problem are you seeing?

Comment: the situation is, the device is really faster than simulator. To test out this, I just try to move an UIImageView by dragging. I found out that the speed of dragging is faster in iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often people are finding this to be a problem because they are doing something intensive in the touchesMoved handler and when events arrive very frequently, it makes the interface appear to lag.

A relatively simple way to deal with this is: First of all, in the touchesMoved handler, store the touch position in a variable that represents the position of whatever is tracking the finger.

Return from the touchesMoved handler immediately. Create an NSTimer object and set your view controller as a delegate of it and have that do whatever re-drawing/view moving behaviour used to be in your touchesMoved handler. Thus, you get a near constant movement regardless of the time between touchesMoved events.

If you're really advanced you can use a custom NSRunLoop instead of using a timer, but that's more than I can explain here :) The general idea is: don't be doing everything in the touch event handlers.